# Mongoose aggregate internal lookup grouping by field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, grouping, aggregate, lookup

I'm trying to group all distinct fields and then lookup into another table , the problem is that I'm adding too many results for the same user inside the lookup, so I wonder how can I group those results internally and then in the next stage add another lookup to a different table.
Currently I have the following code:

```
Post.aggregate([
    { "$group" : {"_id" : { "id_fanpage": "$id_fanpage" },"total": { $sum: 1 } } },
    {
      "$lookup": {
        "from": "v3_post_reaccion_angry",
        "localField": "_id.id_fanpage",
        "foreignField": "id_fanpage",
        "as": "resultingAngries"
      }
    },
    {
      "$lookup": {
        "from": "v3_post_reaccion_compartir",
        "localField": "_id.id_fanpage",
        "foreignField": "id_fanpage",
        "as": "resultingCompartir"
      }
    }
  ]).exec(function(err, results){
    console.log(results);
    return results
  }).then(success(res))
```

What I'm trying to do is distinct Post rows by "id_fanpage", then join another table by that returned id_fanpage, which is basically working as expected, the results are this:

```
{
        "_id": {
            "id_fanpage": "5a63a96d1aa940ca0ada1c82"
        },
        "total": 831,
        "resultingAngries": [
            {
                "_id": "5a71ccda1aa940dd154caf83",
                "id_post": "5a71ccda1aa940dd154caf82",
                "id_fanpage": "5a63a96d1aa940ca0ada1c82",
                "facebook_usuario_id": 345346565665,
                "facebook_usuario_nombre": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5a71cd6b1aa940dd154ddb43",
                "id_post": "5a71cd6b1aa940dd154ddb40",
                "id_fanpage": "5a63a96d1aa940ca0ada1c82",
                "facebook_usuario_id": "44444444444444444",
                "facebook_usuario_nombre": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5a71d7f61aa940dd156b60f4",
                "id_post": "5a71d7f61aa940dd156b60e9",
                "id_fanpage": "5a63a96d1aa940ca0ada1c82",
                "facebook_usuario_id": "asdf12345232421",
                "facebook_usuario_nombre": "YYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5a71cde11aa940dd154ec514",
                "id_post": "5a71cde11aa940dd154ec513",
                "id_fanpage": "5a63a96d1aa940ca0ada1c82",
                "facebook_usuario_id": "asdf2345234555",
                "facebook_usuario_nombre": "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5a71cdcb1aa940dd154e917a",
                "id_post": "5a71cdcb1aa940dd154e9178",
                "id_fanpage": "5a63a96d1aa940ca0ada1c82",
                "facebook_usuario_id": "44444444444444444",
                "facebook_usuario_nombre": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
            }
        ]
        }
```

Now the problem is, I want to group all results inside resultingAngries by facebook_usuario_id and also be able to add the the same to the next lookup, but as far as I know I cannot use a group after the first lookup without affecting the next lookup.
So the result should be:

```
{
        "_id": {
            "id_fanpage": "5a63a96d1aa940ca0ada1c82"
        },
        "total": 831,
        "resultingAngries": [
            {
                "_id": "this is my user id 1111111111",
                "count": N,
            },
            {
                "_id": "this is my user id 2222222222",
                "count": Y,
            }
         ],
        "resultingLikes": [
            {
                "_id": "this is my user id 1111111111",
                "count": N,
            },
            {
                "_id": "this is my user id 2222222222",
                "count": Y,
            }
         ],
   },
   {
    "_id": {
            "id_fanpage": "5a63a96d1aa942345wedf23455s"
        },
        "total": 20,
        "resultingLikes": [
            {
                "_id": "this is my user id 1111111111",
                "count": N,
            },
            {
                "_id": "this is my user id 2222222222",
                "count": Y,
            }
         ],
   },
     "resultingAngries": [
        {
            "_id": "this is my user id 1111111111",
            "count": N,
        },
        {
            "_id": "this is my user id 2222222222",
            "count": Y,
        }
     ],
```

And so on.
I already have seen aggregate, and lookups and not sure if $addToSet can make it, because I cannot group internally so far so applying addToSet is giving me hard times. Help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert below three stages between your $lookup's.

The below steps [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) `resultingAngries` array followed by first [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to count the distinct combination of `facebook_usuario_id` & `id_fanpage` and second `$group` to [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) the `count` and `facebook_usuario_id` back into `resultingAngries` array.

```
  {"$unwind":"$resultingAngries"},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":{
      "id_fanpage":"$_id.id_fanpage",
      "facebook_usuario_id":"$resultingAngries.facebook_usuario_id"
    },
    "total":{"$first":"$total"},
    "count":{"$sum":1}
  }},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":{"id_fanpage":"$_id.id_fanpage"},
    "total":{"$first":"$total"},
    "resultingAngries":{
      "$push":{
        "_id":"$_id.facebook_usuario_id",
        "count":"$count"
      }
    }
  }}
```

Comment: facebook_usuario_id is in the other collection, in the Post collection I have _id, id_fanpage.. in the second collection I have my facebook_usuario_id which is related to Post collection by id_fanpage, so you suggest to add this stages before the first lookup right? or after the first lookup? I'm trying but I received in both cases an empty [ ] what do you think could be?

Comment: Try adding it after  first lookup. Let me verify with your provided data.

Comment: It's working but only with one lookup if I add more lookups time grows up and results start to be not very accurate, so with that done in one lookup I can manage the rest in different functions and then transform the data and output the final result. I tried adding the first stage as I have it followd by the lookup and then added your three stages

Comment: Yeah chaining lookup's  is not a good idea as it doesn't scale well. Keep separate lookup's and do the aggregation in the client code.

Comment: Thank you very very very much, this is I think the hardest query I've ever tried. Thanks a lot.